# Ruby C gem memory pollution between runs

Tags: c, ruby, rubygems

I wrote a gem in C that appears to be keeping polluted memory between runs.

I noticed this in the past, but have finally discovered how to reproduce it consistently by calling the Gem in RSpec with Spring. When running this single RSpec example after restarting Spring, the example always passes. But subsequent runs without restarting Spring result in garbage data. Further subsequent runs result in the **same** garbage data.

Example:

```
$ spring stop
Spring stopped.
$ spring rspec ..._spec.rb:122
...
1 example, 0 failures

$ spring rspec ..._spec.rb:122
...
Failures:
...
       expected collection contained:  [7]
       actual collection contained:    [1333155159]
$ spring rspec ..._spec.rb:122
...
Failures:
...
       expected collection contained:  [7]
       actual collection contained:    [1333155159]

$ spring stop
Spring stopped.
$ spring rspec ..._spec.rb:122
...
1 example, 0 failures

$ spring rspec ..._spec.rb:122
...
Failures:
...
       expected collection contained:  [7]
       actual collection contained:    [117372691]
$ spring rspec ..._spec.rb:122
...
Failures:
...
       expected collection contained:  [7]
       actual collection contained:    [117372691]
```

The C should not be persisting anything between runs. The only global declarations are constants, struct definitions, functions, and the module name itself. For example (simplified to only one of each type of declaration, except for headers):

```
#include <ruby.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SOME_CONSTANTS 100

struct some_structs {
  long id;
  double amount;
};

static long some_functions();

VALUE MyModuleName = Qnil;
VALUE internal_function_name(VALUE self, VALUE rb_data, VALUE rb_options);

void Init_my_gem() {
  MyModuleName = rb_define_module("MyModuleName");
  rb_define_singleton_method(MyModuleName, "exposed_function_name",
    internal_function_name, 2);
}
```

Thank you for any ideas you may have as to what is going on.

**EDIT**

I've isolated it to this:

```
printf("A orders[0].products[0]->id: %lu\n", orders[0].products[0]->id);
VALUE rb_best_orders = rb_ary_new();
printf("B orders[0].products[0]->id: %lu\n", orders[0].products[0]->id);

Output:
A orders[0].products[0]->id: 7
B orders[0].products[0]->id: 140735021913496
```

Note that orders was defined as `struct order *orders;`, and the memory for it was acquired via malloc.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour when a C struct or persistent variable contains a  `VALUE` which if not handled correctly to maintain it can get garbage collected. I don't see anything like that in your example, but is there perhaps such a variable somewhere in your gem? Are there any such C `struct`s presented as Ruby objects using `Data_Wrap_Struct`?

Comment: Thank you @NeilSlater. I do return a `VALUE` from the singleton method:   ```VALUE rb_best_results = rb_ary_new();
  ...
  return rb_best_results;```

Comment: That's an `Array` of course - is a new one generated on each call, or are you trying to cache the result in C? Where do the contents of the array come from - always constructed as new objects in the method?

Comment: Yes, a new one is generated on each call. I'm not trying to store anything in C. The Array consists of Ruby Hashes — instantiated via `rb_hash_new` — which are themselves populated via `rb_hash_aset(rb_array_value, ID2SYM(rb_intern("somestring")), DBL2NUM(somedouble))` and something similar, but with a `rb_ary_new`

Comment: I think we need a compilable example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `ALLOC_N` instead of `malloc`. http://clalance.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-ruby-extensions-in-c-part-12.html was helpful, though it says malloc should work.

Comment: This cropped up again after updating Ruby by a point version (maybe just a coincidence of timing?). I ended up copying all data to local variables and freeing the heap variables prior to calling rb_ary_new.